# How to create one instance of WebDriver per thread for parallel execution

Tags: multithreading, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am taking input for test from Data Provider where Data Provider is used in parallel.
Method will run in parallel so i want to create separate instance of WebDriver per method

Tried till now:

```java
public class Demo {
 private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriverThreadLocal= new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
 public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName());

@BeforeMethod
public  void beforeMethod() {
    WebDriver driver=null;
    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    Random random = new Random();
    int cnt=random.nextInt(2);

    if(cnt == 0) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println(" New Firefox Driver Instantiated");
        log.info("New Firefox Driver Instantiated");
    } 
    else if(cnt == 1) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path");
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println(" New Chrome Driver Instantiated");
        log.info("New Chrome Driver Instantiated"); 
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriverThreadLocal.set(driver);
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp1")
public  void testPrelogin(TestCase testCase) {
     WebDriver driver = webDriverThreadLocal.get();
     //here call static methods of different classes for each screen
}

@DataProvider(name ="dp1",parallel=true)
public Object[][] dp() {
return new Object[][] {
  new Object[] { 1, "a" },
  new Object[] { 2, "b" },

};
}

 @AfterMethod
public void afterClass() {
    WebDriver driver = webDriverThreadLocal.get();
    System.out.println("In after method for id:"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" "+driver);
    driver.quit();
}
```

Testng.xml

```xml
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" data-provider-thread-count="2"> 
   <test name="prelogin" >
      <classes>
        <class name="com.package.Demo"  />   
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

With the above code multiple browsers are launched but out of 2 test atleast one of my test fails as browser screen becomes blank.
Is it because in some way thread resources are shared like webDriver or any other issue?

Comment: Your above code there is not shared webdriver issue. I think there is another issue. Can you please provide more details or errortrace to identify issue!

Comment: I get blank screen while executing test case but the blank screen is not same always. Sometimes 2nd screen is blank then sometimes 3rd. On each screen i am select some elements so if screen is blank then i get element not found type of exceptions. this happens only when i execute in parallel